# How to assign a data type in a cells spreadJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, spreadsheet, wijmo

I am using a "spreadJS" I found it wonderful component like Excel but the worry is I can not assigned a type like (integer, string, combo box, date) for cells are there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

seems spreadjs can set checkbox, combobox, and hyperlink to cell, maybe is what you want.